# c++: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target’

Tags: c++, cmake, clang++

Im compiling a program I made using `make` and I get this error

```
c++: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target’
make[3]: *** [libs/system/CMakeFiles/system.dir/build.make:76: libs/system/CMakeFiles/system.dir/src/system/syscalls.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:504: libs/system/CMakeFiles/system.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:243: CMakeFiles/image-uefi.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:137: image-uefi] Error 2
```

Im running Arch Linux with Clang-13, CMake and all of base-devel installed.

Any help would be appreciated, please dont be condescending I just installed Arch Linux and am getting this error, in Fedora compiling the exact same app provides no error.

The line which created the error is this, it should be the offending linux since the error in question(the top line) complains about -target being unrecognized.

```
cd /home/user/toy-kernel/build/libs/system && /usr/bin/c++ -I/home/user/toy-kernel/libs/system/src -target x86_64-none-elf -mcmodel=kernel -fno-exceptions -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-rtti -nostdlib -ffreestanding -fno-threadsafe-statics -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mno-sse2 -mno-sse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mno-sse4a -mno-3dnow -mno-3dnowa -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT libs/system/CMakeFiles/system.dir/src/system/syscalls.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/system.dir/src/system/syscalls.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/system.dir/src/system/syscalls.cpp.o -c /home/user/toy-kernel/libs/system/src/system/syscalls.cpp
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the actual compilation line that's failing.  `make VERBOSE=1`.  The working one for the same file would be good too.

Comment: Here!:cd /home/user/toy-kernel/build/libs/system && /usr/bin/c++  -I/home/user/toy-kernel/libs/system/src -target x86_64-none-elf -mcmodel=kernel -fno-exceptions -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-rtti -nostdlib -ffreestanding -fno-threadsafe-statics -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mno-sse2 -mno-sse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mno-sse4a -mno-3dnow -mno-3dnowa -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT libs/system/CMakeFiles/system.dir/src/system/syscalls.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/system.dir/src/system/syscalls.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/system.dir/src/system/syscalls.cpp.o -c /home/user/toy-kernel/libs/system/src/system/syscalls.cpp

Comment: Don't post that as a comment, [edit] your question.  And make sure you provide both the working and failing command lines (label which is which).

Comment: Are you sure that `/usr/bin/c++` is clang 13? Do `/usr/bin/c++ --version` or whatever it takes to have it print out its  version.

Comment: lol, yes I ran clang++ --version and c++ --version, its clang 13

Comment: c++(as a command) is a gnu util, its g++

Comment: Since `c++` on your system is not clang, it would be unexpected if it recognised clang-specific options. If you want to use clang, you need to tell CMake to use clang.

Comment: wait -target is clang specific? Do you know how to make c++ clang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, c++ was the g++ compiler instead of the clang compiler, if you are having a similar issue try updating g++ or clang++(on older macs you may need to have to use brew to install those) or going in your /usr/bin directory(for mac and linux, I never used windows cant help you) and replacing the files(though only do that if you absolutely know what your doing!).